# Urban legend short story, possibly called "No Future" Published before 2006-2010

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

**FIRST SUMMARY:** The Urban Legend is about a group of friends who go see a psychic. The psychic tells everyone their future except for one girl. She writes it down and the girl is upset but promises not to read it until she gets home. In the car, she falls asleep and they make a turn and she falls out, dying. The note says that she has no future.

**SECOND SUMMARY:** A girl and a group of friends decided to visit a psychic, and I think she was the last to go. When she entered the room alone with the psychic, the psychic got a terrible headache and started going crazy or something. She then began to write something on a note, and handed it folded to the girl. The psychic then tells her not to open it until she was home. The girl continues to say how she couldn't wait to get home with her boyfriend so she can read what the note said with him. At the end of the story there is just this newspaper article about this girl who had died because she fell asleep leaning against an unlocked car door from the inside, and she had accidently opened it while sleeping and fell out and died. The article said something about her having a note in her hands saying 'NO FUTURE'.

Comment: Is “Urban Legend” a website? Or an author? Or something else?

Comment: Doesn't sound like science fiction or fantasy to me.

Comment: As per the [tour], You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the check mark by the voting buttons.

Comment: @user14111 Psychics with actual precog powers sounds fairly fantastical to me.

Comment: @WiggotheWookie One hit doesn't prove "actual precog powers". For example, in real life, Jeane Dixon "predicted" the Kennedy assassination. Predicting a bad outcome for a customer seems like a poor business model, but doesn't make the story "fantastical", not does having the "prediction" happen to "come true".

Comment: It is fantasy becauses pshycics are fake

Comment: Please don't post answers as part of your question.  And don't change the title.

Comment: You can post a new answer, and even switch acceptance to it by clicking on the checkmark. No issue for me.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I have done what you just sugested

Comment: I saw. Glad to know you found a better match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**FIRST SUMMARY:** The Urban Legend is about a group of friends who go see a psychic. The psychic tells everyone their future except for one girl. She writes it down and the girl is upset but promises not to read it until she gets home. In the car, she falls asleep and they make a turn and she falls out, dying. The note says that she has no future.

**SECOND SUMMARY:** A girl and a group of friends decided to visit a psychic, and I think she was the last to go. When she entered the room alone with the psychic, the psychic got a terrible headache and started going crazy or something. She then began to write something on a note, and handed it folded to the girl. The psychic then tells her not to open it until she was home. The girl continues to say how she couldn't wait to get home with her boyfriend so she can read what the note said with him. At the end of the story there is just this newspaper article about this girl who had died because she fell asleep leaning against an unlocked car door from the inside, and she had accidently opened it while sleeping and fell out and died. The article said something about her having a note in her hands saying 'NO FUTURE'.

**ANOTHER VERSION**

The Short Story is also know as "The Future" by "S.E. Schlosser"

*"She was nervous and excited as she approached the psychic’s store. Normally, she didn’t go in for fortune telling. But her best friend had visited the psychic a few months ago, and everything the woman had predicted came true. Everything! The new boyfriend, the new job, the marriage proposal, a small win in the local lottery. Obviously, the psychic was a genius!
The room she entered was surprisingly open and pleasant. She smelled coffee in the air, and fresh flowers were on a stand by the window. She smiled to herself. Somehow, she had pictured an old gypsy caravan and a dark-haired woman in flowing robes. But the pert, crisp woman approaching her did not look psychic at all.
They sat down at the table, and the woman did a reading of her palm. The psychic frowned a bit in concentration. Then the psychic asked if she would like a Tarot card reading too — free of charge. That was different from what had happened to her best friend. For a moment she felt a trace of unease. Then she shrugged and said okay.
The psychic studied the cards carefully. Then she looked at her palm one more time. Finally, the psychic looked up into her eyes, realized that she was feeling nervous, and said soothingly: “Your future is very clear, my dear. I’ve recently changed my policies, and now put my predictions in a sealed envelope for my customers to read in the privacy of their homes. It is to show customers my credibility in the psychic arts — that I am not “reading their expressions”, but have truly seen something in the palm and cards.”
She blinked a bit, but was impressed. It made sense, after a fashion. The psychic had asked her no questions at all, just read her palm and the cards. So any prediction she put in the envelope would be proof of her powers. The psychic hurried into a back room, where she could hear the faint sound of pen and paper. Then the woman returned with an envelope.
“Thank you,” she said to the psychic, and shook her hand. Then she hurried out to the car, eager to get home and read the predictions in the envelope. What would they be? A rich husband? A career change? Travel to exotic places?
She had just pulled out into the fast lane on the highway when a semi-truck swerved to miss a careless sedan that pulled into the lane right in front of it. She had a single glimpse of a massive shape coming toward her when the truck slammed into her car, crushing it completely against the cement divider.
When the girl’s body was removed from the wreckage, the envelope was found lying beside her. It was presented to her grieving parents, who opened it. The note inside contained four words: “You have no future.”*

**No Future as retold by Waylon Jordan**

*Kathryn did NOT believe in psychics, thank you very much.  But…things had not been going well.  Her boyfriend had left her.  She’d lost her job, and at this point, what could it hurt to just visit Madame Rosa’s salon and see what the woman had to say.  Her friend Sarah had gone on and on about how accurate Rosa was.
She parked across the street from the little storefront that was Madame Rosa’s Psychic Salon and made her way quickly over so that no one she knew would see her going inside.
Kathryn stared around at the strange objects on the shelves and counters inside Madame Rosa’s.  Crystal balls, tarot cards, little statues of fairies and elves.  There seemed to be something in every corner to catch the eye.
“Welcome,” a sultry whiskey voice sounded behind her.
Kathryn turned quickly to find Madame Rosa sitting at a small table in the corner.  A small blue crystal ball glowed in front of her, casting the psychic in a softly dramatic glow.
She’s certainly got her act down, Kathryn thought, though she was a bit unnerved by the woman’s sudden appearance.
“Hello…I…my name is Kathryn and I’d like to have my fortune told.”
Madame Rosa smiled and motioned for the chair on the other side of the table.  Kathryn slowly made her way over and sat down.
“Things haven’t been going so well, lately,” she began.  “Nothing seems to be going my way.”
“Well,” replied the psychic, “everyone has a rough patch from time to time, but let us see what the future holds.  Give me your hands.”
Feeling more than a little foolish, Kathryn extended her arms across the table and laid her hands, palms up, in Madame Rosa’s.
The psychic stared at her palms for a long time, turning Kathryn’s hands this way and that.  Shaking her head, she dropped Kathryn’s hands to the table.
“I’m sorry.  There is no charge, but I cannot tell your future.”
“What?!  Why not?” Kathryn demanded.
“I simply cannot.  Please, you must leave here, now!”
“Look, lady, I came here to have my fortune told and that’s exactly what you’re going to do!”
“I cannot!” Madam Rosa stood so fast that her chair turned over.  “This is my establishment and I do not have to do anything I do not want to here.”
Kathryn continued to badger the woman, demanding that she be told what the woman saw.  If she hadn’t been so angry, she would have realized just how scared she was in that moment.  Finally, Madame Rosa snatched up a sheet of paper and scribbled on it.
“There!  That is what I saw.  But promise me, give me your oath that you will not read it until you are inside your own home.”
Kathryn took the paper and shoved it into her pocket.  “Fine, you have my word,” and she stormed out the front door of the salon.
Deep in thought over what could be written on that paper and still furious with the woman for putting up such a front, Kathryn wasn’t paying attention.  She stepped from the curb and was hit by a bus, dying instantly.
The police soon arrived on the scene and began their investigation.  While they were searching for identification, they found a sheet of paper in Kathryn’s pocket but the words scrawled across it puzzled them.  Was it a threat?  A suicide note?  What else could “You have no future” mean?*

Answer (score 7):

Could it be this "[No Future](https://www.wattpad.com/amp/462436726)" by PrincessAvatarRose?

> She had just pulled out into the fast lane on the highway when a semi-truck swerved to miss a careless sedan that pulled into the lane right in front of it. She had a single glimpse of a massive shape coming toward her when the truck slammed into her car, crushing it completely against the cement divider.
>
> When the girl's body was removed from the wreckage, the envelope was found lying beside her. It was presented to her grieving parents, who opened it. The note inside contained four words: "You have no future."

It wouldn't surprise me if this is an older story than that, and this is just one of the reproductions. Is there a particular version you're looking for?

Comment: Yes that is it but I am looking for an older version.

Comment: @PaulFrancis: Do you know when you read it before?

Comment: See, that's one mean psychic. They knew that she would die and would never read the note, but they had to mock her anyway.

Comment: Or it's a Cassandra kind of situation where they have to tell the truth, but no one ever believes them.

Comment: There was a short story by some golden age writer about creating a machine that accurately determined how long you would live.  Part of the story is his refusing to give his prediction to a young couple because they would die that same afternoon.  So the concept has been around for a while.